# Should I stay with my employer to receive shares?

Tags: careers

I'm currently in my notice period, and due to join a new employer soon.

But my current employer wants me to stay, and has just offered me shares (not share options) in the company if I stay. They've started giving shares to employees who have been at the company for more than 18 months (it's a startup, the company's only been in business for 2 years). They've been pretty vague about values, but a figure of £50k has been suggested. It's a niche product area, so after four years (after which I'll be able to keep 100% of the shares even if I leave) they might have doubled in value. Maybe more, but this isn't FB or anything remotely similar so who knows!

My new role is more senior, with more responsibilities and a *significant* pay rise, and in an interesting product area. Slightly longer hours too, it's not all good ;)

There's little career progression if I stay, it'll be purely a monetary thing. I'm not unhappy in my current role, but I'm not entirely fulfilled either.

So I'm in a dilemma. Am I shooting myself in the foot if I stay? But if I leave, then I'm losing out on the shares, which after a few years could have a significant value.

Comment: *which after a few years could have a significant value*.. yeah, they could also be worth way less.

Comment: It's unlikely they'll just give you shares. Most likely there will be a vesting period involved, where you have to work x number of additional years before you actually own the shares.

Comment: This is just a trick to make people more loyal. I have been offered this many times, but in the end, if i want the stocks, i can just buy them as any other stocks. Why should i feel like there is some reward for me for being allowed to buy something?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie - after 1 year I'd keep 25% of the shares, after 2 years 50%, 3 years 75%, and 4 years 100%. So I'd have to stay at the company for at least 4 years in order to fully own the shares I'm given.

Comment: We're just strangers. We can't say what you should do. Do you want a better role and to be happier in your job, or (the potential for) not that but more money? Many people choose both those options. How can we say which is right for you?

Comment: So at the very least you need to not think of the share value as one sum (the "£50k") but as the sum divided by 4. So even if they do end up worth £50k, it would be more like a salary increase of £12.5k (that only lasts for 4 years, and could well be worth £0)

Comment: Shares of a private company, are only worth, what somebody is willing to pay for them.  They could be worthless tomorrow.  You will have to stay 4 years in a job you are unhappy with.  We can't help you make this decision.

Answer (score 4):

The shares could have doubled, or trippled, or more.
Or they could be worth 0. And for startups, while some Unicorns are worth a lot, most of them approach a value of 0.

You are taking a gamble. So it's up to you and your values to decide:
Do you want to gamble your time, so you could win big?
Are you willing to not get much out of it?

Or do you value something like career progression more?

And don't take their suggested value at face value. Do your own investigation, at least confirm how they came up with this numbers.
They may be honest, it still could be wishful thinking on their part.